# Getting 405 Error Method Not Allowed on my AJAX POST call to my Web API

Tags: ajax, api, post, cors

I'm trying to call my Web API Function from an AJAX POST call but keep getting a 405 Error.  I've been looking but only been finding solutions saying to Enable CORS, which I've done, but to no avail.  For now, I'm just trying to display the data in html.  The user enters in an Order Number and that fills in the parameter for the Web API Function.  Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

My **Web API Function**:

```
<Route("{ordNbr}/contents")>
<HttpGet>
Public Function GetOrderContents(ByVal ordNbr As String) As SPFolderOver

    Dim retValue As ReturnVal
    retValue = GetOrderInformation(ordNbr)
    Dim sp = New Sharepoint()
    Dim t = sp.GetOrderContent(retValue.Year, retValue.SONumber)
    Dim contentFolder = New SPFolderOver()
    contentFolder = SPFolderOver.LoadFolder(t)
    contentFolder.FolderName = t.FullPath
    Return contentFolder
End Function
```

My **AJAX call**:

```
function GetOrder() {


        var order = document.getElementById("orderNbr").value;

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:54754/orders/{ordNbr}/contents",
            data: { 'ordNbr': order },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#orderContents").html(data);
            }
        });

    };
```

In my **global.asax**

```
Protected Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    If (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod = "OPTIONS") Then
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
    End If

End Sub
```

In my **Web.config**

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Olaround-Debug-Mode, Authorization, Accept" />
    <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="X-Olaround-Debug-Mode, X-Olaround-Request-Start-Timestamp, X-Olaround-Request-End-Timestamp, X-Olaround-Request-Time, X-Olaround-Request-Method, X-Olaround-Request-Result, X-Olaround-Request-Endpoint" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: In the `Network` tab in Chrome, what do you see when you call GetOrder()? Is the Ajax call properly formed? Do you see the correct value for `ordNbr`? What response / data do you get back from the server? It would help if you could add a screenshot of the error to your post.

Comment: In the `Network` tab, I'm getting back `{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}`  along with `%7BordNbr%7D`.

Comment: I changed my AJAX call from `POST` to `GET` and that seems to pull the data through when I inspect the browser page.  Now I just have to get the data to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you where able to debug using the `Network` tab. As a note, I recommend naming the JSON response `response` to make the distinction with the input `data`.

```
function GetOrder() {
    var order = document.getElementById("orderNbr").value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: { 'ordNbr': order },
        url: "http://localhost:54754/orders/{ordNbr}/contents)",
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            $("#orderContents").html(response);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("Error: " + err.errorText);
        }
   });
}
```